# How to add value to existing key in a map data type?

Tags: dart

I have a map data type, Map<String, List>, (todoData) and I want to add more strings to the list value.

```
final Map<String, List<String>> todoDate = {};
```

for example: `{'Today': ['Code', 'Eat',]};`
I want to add a 3rd String to the value, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would recommend not using `Map` as a way to structure data since it gives you all kinds of unsafe behavior we need to deal with. e.g. Dart is not able to tell us right away if the map contains the key `"Today"` already.

If it does not contain the key, we need to define a new list with our new entry instead of just adding to an existing one.

We can use the [`update`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-core/Map/update.html) function on `Map` to handle both cases like this:

```dart
void main() {
  final Map<String, List<String>> todoDate = {
    'Today': ['Code', 'Eat']
  };

  todoDate.update('Today', (list) => list..add('Learn Dart'),
      ifAbsent: () => ['Learn Dart']);

  print(todoDate); // {Today: [Code, Eat, Learn Dart]}
}
```

Personally, I don't really like this since we need a lot of code. We can, however, reduce the amount of code by adding an extension method to `Map` which contains `List` as values (name of extension and method should be renamed to something better):

```
void main() {
  final Map<String, List<String>> todoDate = {
    'Today': ['Code', 'Eat']
  };

  todoDate.appendToList('Today', 'Learn Dart');
  todoDate.appendToList('Yesterday', 'Learn Dart');

  print(todoDate); // {Today: [Code, Eat, Learn Dart], Yesterday: [Learn Dart]}
}

extension AppendToListOnMapWithListsExtension<K, V> on Map<K, List<V>> {
  void appendToList(K key, V value) =>
      update(key, (list) => list..add(value), ifAbsent: () => [value]);
}
```

But if we already know right away what keys we have in the `Map` (so keys are not dynamically created), we could instead just define a class. What this class should look like depends a lot of the application. But a simple example would be:

```dart
class Todo {
  final List<String> _tasks = [];

  void addTask(String task) => _tasks.add(task);
  void removeTask(String task) => _tasks.remove(task);

  @override
  String toString() => 'Todo: $_tasks';
}

void main() {
  final todayTasks = Todo()
    ..addTask('Code')
    ..addTask('Eat');

  todayTasks.addTask('Learn Dart');
  todayTasks.removeTask('Code');

  print(todayTasks); // Todo: [Eat, Learn Dart]
}
```

Maybe have some other class that contains the `todayTasks` variable. But the question does not really give enough context to come up with a detailed class design. :)

Comment: What do you recommend to use instead of Map?

Comment: A class. I will add it to my answer with an example.

Comment: @AliHazem Example added. Not really a great example but at least something to start with. I recommend reading: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#classes

Comment: I have been struggling on how to iterate through, {'Today': ['code', 'read'], 'Tomorrow': ['code', 'read']}. I want to display a title, or in other words text, of the key with listview builder of values. I tried nesting for-loops, maping, but i couldnt do the job. Could you help?

Comment: @AliHazem My answer are for the question being asked. If the question does not provide important context, my answer will have the risk of not fitting your need. Sorry, but I cannot help you any further.

Answer (score 2):

For adding to a list, use:

```
List<int> list = [1, 2, 3];
list.add(4);
```

For removing from a list:

```
list2.remove(2); // Remove the value "2"
list2.removeAt(0); // Remove the value at index 0
```

So, for your case, you can do:

```
todoDate["Today"]?.add("myNewValue"); // Add new value if 'Today' key exists.
```

For removing:

```
todoDate["Today"]?.remove("myNewValue"); // Remove the value "myNewValue"
todoDate["Today"]?.removeAt(2); // Remove the value at index 2
```

Comment: It shouldn't even compile because of null-safety. You have to add at least null-check operator.

Comment: @Wiktor You are right, I have updated my answer.